# Kubuntu 20.04 - Backscreen on boot after dist-upgrade

Tags: boot, 20.04, updates

I did update my PC with apt update + apt dist-upgrade.
After the update a started a VMWare machine and it warned that no hardware graphics was available.

I ran glxinfo and it just showed some errors that it could not find a device,
and then a decided to give a reboot a try.

- Rebooted, asked for boot password, accepted and got stuck on a black screen.
- Rebooted another time and ended again with a black screen
- Rebooted - grub menu and selected the normal option

  - [image: Picture from normal boot]
- Rebooted again -> grub menu and selected an ealier entrypoint from timeshift

  - 1 december 2021 13:22:39 (vmlinuz-5.11.0-40-generic & initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic)
  - With this version I can fully boot into Kubuntu
  - (I think it's version 5.11.0-41 that is causing the problems)
- Tried to edit `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"` + `sudo update-grub`

  - This did not change anything and ended up with black screen again
- Tried `sudo update-initramfs -u`

  - This ended with errors:
    [image: Results from update-initramfs -u]

Can someone help me about what's wrong and how I can repair this?
For now I'm running with one from timeshift.
PC was intalled for about a year ago and I have updated a lot of times since.

---

System:
OS = Kubuntu 20.04

- Everything is encrypted incl boot
- brtfs file system
- timeshift is installed

Graphics = GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (NVIDIA-SMI 470.86)
`chp@workstation:~$ prime-select query => nvidia`

Answer (score 0):

A post mentioned that the `update-initramfs` could fail if there was not enough space on /boot.
At a run with `apt autoremove` timeshift screwed badly up in things and i could not boot at all anymore.
Booted to a live disk and from there with chroot it was possible to cleanup /boot and generate new `update-initramfs`.
Timeshift made a lot of problems where the OS looked to drop or lock the file systems, so I ended up with purgeing 'timeshift' and 'timeshift-autosnap-apt'.